# When I receive my contract after handing in formal job offer

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment, applications, contracts

Ive got a question for you.

Last month I have applied for the job position

- After couple days they called me with an interview.
- Attended to the interview - successful and after another couple days I had phone call that they have job for me.
- I have  received my formal  job offer letter  + application  by the email  asking me to fill in those and bring them back to the site and they will generate contract for me - which will be send from the main office

I have done all the steps and  now im waiting for my contract as i have already put notice in my present job.

It is UK employer, based in the UK - big retail company

My question is, How long this process should take - until I receive my contract ?

Now its exactly 7 days after I have handed my documents and job offer letter in  to my future employer,

Should  I contact HR asking when can expect my contract or should I wait any longer as I dont want to be pushy -  i have already  noticed  my present employer so im bit worried that i haven't signed any written contract but i have formal offer.

Many Thanks Guys

P.

Comment: You should definitely contact them NOW.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I contact HR asking when can expect my contract

Yes. Call them now and ask.

Next time you go through this sort of hiring process, always ask up front what the next step will be and when that will happen. Make sure you leave each step being clear what will occur next and when.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the formal offer (which you have formally accepted) and assuming that was unconditional (i.e. there wasn't any language around the offer being subject to references, background checks or health etc) then legally speaking you *have* got [a binding contract of employment](https://www.gov.uk/job-offers-your-rights) with them. So there isn't really any need to worry that it's "just" an offer. An "actual" contract may provide you with more "buffer" in terms of a longer than statutory notice period but that's about it.

Actual job contracts can take a while to work their way through the machinery of bureaucracy etc.

Comment: I have a very bad feeling where the OP says "formal job offer" (dot point three), the OP only got chitty word talk on the phone; and then in the phrase following that the "letter" refers only to some form to fill in for a coming step.

Comment: @Fattie That **does** constitute a formal job offer in the UK

Answer (score 0):

No harm in asking for your contract or a date when you can expect to get it if you have not done so.

Maybe they've sent it and it has been lost in transit.

I believe that UK companies actually have 2 Months from your start date to provide you with written details of your contract but obviously a contract would have to exist when you begin working for them even if it's verbal.